# Streaming OrientDB graphs to Gephi

Tags: orientdb, gephi, orientdb2.2

I've been trying to stream an `Orientdb (v. 2.2.3)` `graph` to `Gephi (v. 0.9.1)` for visualization.

The data loads and it's visible in the data laboratory. But the graph isn't displayed. I think the problem may be that the `Gephi` `Id field`  is populated by `Orientdb`  `record id` (e.g. #18:0) not an `integer`.

I'm using [this URL](http://localhost:2480/gephi/%3Cdatabasename%3E/sql/select%20from%20V)

Has anyone experienced this issue, and is there a solution?

I'm new to both of these platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried with Gephi 0.9.1 (last available) and the nodes are correctly loaded, but they are not displayed. This is a bug in Gephi, not OrientDB: https://github.com/gephi/gephi/issues/1447.